# How do I change a substring in cells using pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, string

I'm making a program in python that goes through a column in an excel file, which has to find all entries following this regex: '^(Q.*)\-(.*)\.', where it can then put the second group into the second column and only keep the contents of the first group into the first column. The following isn't code; it is just an example of what i want it to do efficiently.:

```
Start:

Col 1          | Col 2

Q324-F2.1_G    | NOTHING

Q134-D4.5_C    | NOTHING

End:
Col 1          | Col 2

Q324           | F2

Q134           | D4
```

I understand that I'd have to use .loc() in some way, but I'm not sure how to set up how to modify the values with regex stuff. I also want to have this code be fast since I'm dealing with massive files and take advantage of vectorization if I can, which is why I'm kinda at an impasse here since I can't just substitute one by one.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using extract.  I updated my answer to preserve non-matching rows.

Starting DF:

```
         Col_1    Col_2
0  W115-D4.5_C  NOTHING
1  Q324-F2.1_G  NOTHING
2  Q134-D4.5_C  NOTHING
3  X134-D4.5_C  NOTHING
```

Do the extract - updating only the matching rows (taking advantage of the fact that NaN != NaN):

```
dfn[['Col_1','Col_2']] = \
    pd.concat([dfn[['Col_1','Col_2']],dfn['Col_1'].str.extract('^(Q.*)\-(.*)\.')], axis=1) \
        .apply(lambda x: x if x[0]==x[0] else x.shift(2), axis=1)[[0,1]]

dfn[['Col_1','Col_2']]

         Col_1    Col_2
0  W115-D4.5_C  NOTHING
1         Q324       F2
2         Q134       D4
3  X134-D4.5_C  NOTHING
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when the regex isn't met

Comment: It will return `NaN`s when the regex is not met.  (At least it did on my augmented test data.)  What do you want to occur in a no-match situation?

Comment: I just want it to return the original/do nothing in a no-match situation. Otherwise this results in most of my data turning into ```NaN```.